# Active Record Lazy Preload Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems, lazy-loading

I'm adding [this](https://github.com/DmitryTsepelev/ar_lazy_preload) gem to my application in the hopes it will help me lazy load some associations and remove some `N+1` queries.

There's an option to configure the gem so that it lazy preloads all associations by default. I'm confused as to where I should place this line in the code?

```rb
ArLazyPreload.config.auto_preload = true
```

My gut is telling me that it should go in the config block in `application.rb` so I've tested it there and restarted my server but I didn't notice any change in the rails logs.

Should this go in the environments folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the solution.

I created an initializer file called `ar_lazy_preload.rb` and added the code in that file. Restart the rails server and boom.

It works!